# Are the WWDC 09 session videos Fairplay-DRM protected?

Tags: iphone, session, video, drm

I would like to buy the »WWDC 2009 iPhone Session Videos« from [ADC](http://developer.apple.com/products/videos.html). But I want to view them on my TV which is capable displaying mp4/h264 m4v (mov) files which you could grab for free on ADC@iTunes some time ago.

Somebody knows if the iPhone WWDC 09 videos comes without any DRM, too? Because my TV isn't able to display rented movies from the iTunes store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have all the Session videos from WWDC'09 and they are all in m4v and unencrypted, so enjoy.

Comment: If you are at all serious about doing this for a living, or even a serious hobby, you'll save far more by watching the videos than they cost.

Comment: Well I attended WWDC so I've seen many of them already, but as Brad said if you are serious about they provide a good source.

Comment: Most of them are pretty good.  If I had not gone I would purchase the set.